# Set state in other react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed other posts on this but couldn't fix it.

I want to set the state from one component in another component.

Here is my minimal example:

```
function setOtherState(param1_new){
  this.setState({param1: param1_new})
}

export default class CompA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  _setOtherState(param1_new) {
    updateShowThis(param1_new); // --> HERE I CALL THE METHOD IN THE OTHER COMPONENT!
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._setOtherState(true)
  }

  ...
}

class CompB extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      param1: false,
    }
    setOtherState = setOtherState.bind(this)
  }
  ...
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('CompA', () => CompA);
AppRegistry.registerComponent("CompB", () => CompB);
```

However, when I run this code, I am getting:

> TypeError: this.setState is not a function

How can I set the state of one component from another one correctly?

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off with some global state for this (e.g. redux or mobx)

Comment: I can agree with the first answer: you have a design smell, very very likely. The state is supposed to be internal to the component. If you want to edit it you call a function on that component, but you do not call setState directly by rebinding `this` on it weirdly.

Comment: I understand its bad design. But it also seems a bit overhead to add another framework for this one function call only? Is there any other way than using another framework?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be setting a component's state with `setState()` directly from another component, ever. The reason your example doesn't work is because

```
function updateShowThis(show){
  this.setState({showThis: show})
}
```

in that function `this` doesn't refer to any component (since the function isn't defined inside a component). But even if it could, if you find you're trying to manipulate the state of a component directly from another using `setState()`, it's a sign you need to revisit your component hierarchy and maybe see if a state management tool like Redux would solve your issue.